# How to better handle/save Python (3.x) exception traces that aren't immediately raised?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, exception

I have an exception class I created that I find extremely handy when dealing with multiple errors, and I would like to improve it.  I call it `AggregateErrors`.

### Background

Basically, it buffers exception objects.  (The code that uses it is left to deal with addressing cascading errors so that the script can otherwise proceed, e.g. skip a row of input data).  I wrote it because we have a scientific data submission interface and the data is always prone to many user errors (improper formatting, data conflicts, missing data, and a whole host of data-specific issues).  The loading script takes a long time to run, and to have to restart the load after encountering individual errors can be a weeks long process.  With my `AggregatedErrors` class, all errors and warnings are buffered, and eventually summarized at the end of the run.  We have a data validation interface that re-uses the same loading code and provides the error summary to the researcher for them to be able to fix issues on their own and then attempt to revalidate.

### The Original Problem

Since the exceptions are raised later, you don't get a trace of where the exception was caught and buffered.

### Mitigation of the original problem

I mitigated this issue by utilizing `traceback.format_stack()` and then appending `traceback.format_tb(exception.__traceback__)`.  (I prune the stack by excluding anything with "site-packages", just so it's not unnecessarily long.)  I then print that "pseudo-trace" anytime my `buffer_error()` method is called.

It's important to note also that `exception.__traceback__` is rarely ever enough to debug an issue and it's usually empty.  Take these 2 pseudo-traces for example from one of my failed tests that I'm currently working on.  It has 2 exceptions related to incorrect handling of the case of the header strings.  Only the second exception had anything in `exception.__traceback__`:

```
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 653, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 593, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 550, in _callTestMethod
    method()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/tests/models/test_model_utilities.py", line 176, in test_handle_load_db_errors_integrityerror
    call_command(
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/management/commands/load_study_table.py", line 70, in handle
    loader.load_study_table()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/loader.py", line 158, in load_wrapper
    self.check_headers()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/loader.py", line 81, in check_headers
    self.aggregated_errors_object.buffer_error(
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/exceptions.py", line 954, in buffer_error
    self.buffer_exception(exception, is_error=True, is_fatal=is_fatal)
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/exceptions.py", line 913, in buffer_exception
    buffered_tb_str = self.get_buffered_traceback_string()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/exceptions.py", line 897, in get_buffered_traceback_string
    for step in traceback.format_stack()
EXCEPTION1(ERROR): UnknownHeadersError: Unknown header(s) encountered: [Study ID, Name, Description] in sheet [Study] in file [Study].
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 653, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 593, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 550, in _callTestMethod
    method()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/tests/models/test_model_utilities.py", line 176, in test_handle_load_db_errors_integrityerror
    call_command(
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/management/commands/load_study_table.py", line 70, in handle
    loader.load_study_table()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/loader.py", line 165, in load_wrapper
    self.aggregated_errors_object.buffer_error(e)
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/exceptions.py", line 954, in buffer_error
    self.buffer_exception(exception, is_error=True, is_fatal=is_fatal)
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/exceptions.py", line 913, in buffer_exception
    buffered_tb_str = self.get_buffered_traceback_string()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/exceptions.py", line 897, in get_buffered_traceback_string
    for step in traceback.format_stack()

The above caught exception had a partial traceback:

  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/loader.py", line 158, in load_wrapper
    self.check_headers()
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/loader.py", line 94, in check_headers
    raise RequiredHeadersError(
EXCEPTION2(ERROR): RequiredHeadersError: Required header(s) missing: [study id, name, description] in sheet [Study] in file [Study].
```

Overall, `AggregatedErrors` works sufficiently well and allows me to debug issues as we further develop our code.

### The Current Problem

The only issues I now have are just annoying ones:

1. The pseudo-traces definitely have more in them than is really needed.
2. Testing unnecessarily spits out all of the printed exception traces (e.g. when the ultimately raised `AggregatedErrors` is caught and handled, e.g. in a `TestCase.assertRaises(AggregatedErrors)`).
3. When you have a lot of tests, it's difficult to match an exception in the summary in each failed test with the printed pseudo-trace somewhere way far back in the terminal window (especially since it also includes printed pseudo-traces from successful tests).

### Questions

1. I have read enough about python traces to know that they are built as the stack is traversed frame-by-frame between where they occur and the catch.  Is there a way to march through that stack without raising, and allowing the script to still proceed, so that I can build a proper traceback on my own?
2. If I don't print the pseudo-trace when the exception is buffered and decide to instead output the group of traces with a raised `AggregatedError` exception, is there a way to include those traces with that exception (perhaps organized in some way to make the summary easy to handle)?
3. If I don't do item `2.`, is there a way to include a searchable identifier to be able to associate an error string with the pseudo-trace?